# Span with href on click

Tags: jquery

I am having a span element which has an href inside, I am performing a click event on span but the event is firing on href as the href is inside span. How can I perform click action only on `span` instead of the `a` element inside it? Here is the sample code

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("span")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  alert('hi');
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <span>TestData <a href='#'>X</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, something is not right in what you are stating. Events do propagate but from child to parent, and not in the other way. If you click on the span only, that means anything outside the red area and inside the green area will be forwarded to the span only. If you click on the link, which is the red area, it will be forwarded to the link **and** to the span also **unless** you stop it from propagating.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("span")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", e => {
  console.log('span clicked')
})

$('span a').on('click', e => { 
  console.log('a clicked')
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

span {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background-color: green;
}

span a {
  padding: .1em 1em;
  background-color: red;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <span>TestData <a href='#'>X</a></span>
</div>
```

---

In case you want to handle the click event on the span element, but do not execute any code if the event is triggered by the anchor tag element inside it, you can check for the event.target object like this:

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <span id="debug">TestData <a href='#'>X</a></span>
</div>
```

```js
button.on("click", function(e){
  // Check if the element that triggered the event, is the one we are looking for:
  if ( e.target.id === "debug" ){
    alert('hi');
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, events do propagate in both directions: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing
@ZorgoZ

Comment: Thanks I got it with this  `if (!$(e.target).is('a')) { }`